# Automatically re-authorize client in oauth2?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I have integrated an oauth2 server with Laravel. But something I am getting a bit stuck on is with the webapp that uses the resources protected via oauth2 we are only logging in via the authorization server, much like sites that have "Sign in with Google" we don't actually have a login form on our site. So I am wondering how we identify the user when they return?

By this I mean that we offer personalization through the webapp that is only relevant in the webapp context, so we have a database there that simply links the personalizations to the user via user_id, we also store the user_id => access_token pair and in subsequent requests we use that access token.

This all works great the first time the user logs in as they are asked to grant access etc. But on subsequent requests the user is again asked by the authorization server to grant access to the webapp instead of just being logged in.

Am I doing something wrong here or should the authorization server - upon identifying a pre-existing client_id and user_id auto-authorize the client? And should the webapp be getting a new access_token on each subsequent session (where the user_id has dropped out of the users session/cookie so we must ask the authorization server to tell us again who the user is).

#### Oauth Controller Code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use \League\OAuth2\Server;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Util\RedirectUri;
use Toddish\Verify\UserDeletedException;
use Toddish\Verify\UserDisabledException;
use Toddish\Verify\UserNotFoundException;
use Toddish\Verify\UserPasswordIncorrectException;
use Toddish\Verify\UserUnverifiedException;

class oAuthController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {
        // Initiate the request handler which deals with $_GET, $_POST, etc
        $request = new Server\Util\Request();

        // Initiate a new database connection
        $connectionString = '';
        $connectionString .= DB::Connection()->getConfig('driver') . '://';
        $connectionString .= DB::Connection()->getConfig('username') . ':';
        $connectionString .= DB::Connection()->getConfig('password') . '@';
        $connectionString .= DB::Connection()->getConfig('host') . '/';
        $connectionString .= DB::Connection()->getConfig('database');
        $db = new Server\Storage\PDO\Db( $connectionString );

        // Create the auth server, the three parameters passed are references
        //  to the storage models
        $this->authserver = new Server\Authorization(
            new Server\Storage\PDO\Client,
            new Server\Storage\PDO\Session,
            new Server\Storage\PDO\Scope
        );

        // Enable the authorisation code grant type
        $this->authserver->addGrantType(new Server\Grant\AuthCode( $this->authserver ));
        $this->authserver->setScopeDelimeter(',');
    }

    public function getIndex() {

        try {

            // Tell the auth server to check the required parameters are in the
            //  query string
            $grant  = $this->authserver->getGrantType('authorization_code');
            $params = $grant->checkAuthoriseParams();

            // Save the verified parameters to the user's session
            Session::put('client_id', $params['client_id']);
            Session::put('client_details', $params['client_details']);
            Session::put('redirect_uri', $params['redirect_uri']);
            Session::put('response_type', $params['response_type']);
            Session::put('scopes', $params['scopes']);

            // Redirect the user to the sign-in route
            return Redirect::action('OauthController@getSignin');

        } catch(Server\Exception\ClientException $e) {

            /**
             * Handle all the fatal errors we shouldn't send back to the client.
             */
            if(Server\Authorization::getExceptionType($e->getCode()) == 'invalid_client') {
                return View::make('oauth.client-error')
                       ->with(Lang::get('oauth.errors.fatal.invalid'))
                       ->with('apiMessage', $e->getMessage());
            } elseif(Str::contains($e->getMessage(), 'Check the "redirect_uri" parameter')) {
                return View::make('oauth.client-error')
                       ->with(Lang::get('oauth.errors.fatal.redirectUri'))
                       ->with('apiMessage', $e->getMessage());
            } elseif(Str::contains($e->getMessage(), 'Check the "client_id" parameter')) {
                return View::make('oauth.client-error')
                       ->with(Lang::get('oauth.errors.fatal.clientId'))
                       ->with('apiMessage', $e->getMessage());
            } else {

                /**
                 * if we got here we know that the client_id and redirect_uri are filled but we cannot assume they are
                 * valid we need to validate the credentials to decide whether to send the user back to the redirect_uri                    * with the error or handle it in house
                 */
                $client        = $this->authserver->getStorage('client');
                $clientDetails = $client->getClient(Input::get('client_id'),
                                                    null,
                                                    urldecode(Input::get('redirect_uri')),
                                                    $grant->getIdentifier());

                /**
                 * Invalid client details, let's handle this issue first.
                 */
                if($clientDetails === false) {
                    return View::make('oauth.client-error')
                           ->with(Lang::get('oauth.errors.fatal.invalid'))
                           ->with('apiMessage', $this->authserver->getExceptionMessage('invalid_client'));
                }

                /**
                 * Valid client credentials - let's redirect the resource owner back to the client with the error.
                 */
                $redirectResponse = [
                    'error'             => Server\Authorization::getExceptionType($e->getCode()),
                    'error_description' => $e->getMessage()
                ];

                return Redirect::to(RedirectUri::make(Input::get('redirect_uri'), $redirectResponse));
            }

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            /**
             * This is a general exception so we should pass this back off to the client with the server_error error
             */

            $redirectResponse = [ ];
        }
    }

    public function getSignin() {
        $params = $this->getParams(false);

        // User is signed in
        if($params['user_id'] !== null) {
            return Redirect::action('OauthController@getAuthorise');
        } else {
            return View::make('oauth.signin', $params);
        }
    }

    public function postSignin() {

        try {

            $validator = Validator::make(
                Input::only([ 'identifier', 'password' ]),
                [ 'identifier' => [ 'required' ], 'password' => [ 'required' ] ]
            );

            if($validator->fails()) {
                $errors = $validator->getMessageBag();
            } else {
                Auth::attempt(Input::only([ 'identifier', 'password' ]), Input::get('remember'));
                Session::put('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

                return Redirect::action('OauthController@getAuthorise');
            }

        } catch(UserNotFoundException $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'identifier' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.signIn.userNotFound') ] );
        } catch(UserUnverifiedException $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'identifier' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.signIn.userNotVerified') ] );
        } catch(UserDisabledException $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'identifier' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.signIn.userDisabled') ] );
        } catch(UserDeletedException $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'identifier' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.signIn.userDeleted') ] );
        } catch(UserPasswordIncorrectException $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'password' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.signIn.userWrongPassword') ] );
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'generic' => $e->getMessage() ] );
        }

        return Redirect::action('OauthController@getSignin')
               ->withErrors($errors)
               ->withInput(Input::only([ 'identifier', 'remember' ]));
    }

    private function getParams($doUserIdCheck = true) {
        // Retrieve the auth params from the user's session
        $params['client_id']      = Session::get('client_id');
        $params['client_details'] = Session::get('client_details');
        $params['redirect_uri']   = Session::get('redirect_uri');
        $params['response_type']  = Session::get('response_type');
        $params['scopes']         = Session::get('scopes');

        // Check that the auth params are all present
        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            if($value === null) {
                // Throw an error because an auth param is missing - don't
                //  continue any further
                $errors = new MessageBag( [ 'error' => 'The request is missing the ' . $key . ' key' ] );
                die();
            }
        }

        // Get the user ID
        $params['user_id'] = Session::get('user_id');

        // User is not signed in so redirect them to the sign-in route (/oauth/signin)
        if($doUserIdCheck && $params['user_id'] === null) {
            return Redirect::action('OauthController@getSignin');
        }

        return $params;
    }

    public function getAuthorise() {

        $params = $this->getParams();
        //if it's not an array we have got back a redirect request
        if(! is_array($params)) {
            return $params;
        }

        // Check if the client should be automatically approved
        $autoApprove = ( $params['client_details']['auto_approve'] === '1' ) ? true : false;

        // Process the authorise request if the user's has clicked 'approve' or the client
        if($autoApprove) {
            // Generate an authorisation code
            $code = $this->authserver->getGrantType('authorization_code')
                    ->newAuthoriseRequest('user', $params['user_id'], $params);

            // Redirect the user back to the client with an authorisation code
            return Redirect::to(
                RedirectUri::make(
                    $params['redirect_uri'],
                    [ 'code' => $code, 'state' => isset( $params['state'] ) ? $params['state'] : '' ]));
        }

        // The client shouldn't automatically be approved so show them a form
        return View::make('oauth.authorise', $params);
    }

    public function postAuthorise() {
        $params = $this->getParams();
        //if it's not an array we have got back a redirect request
        if(! is_array($params)) {
            return $params;
        }

        if(Input::get('approve') !== null) {

            if(Input::get('terms') === null) {
                $e = new MessageBag( [ 'terms' => Lang::get('oauth.errors.authorize.termsNotAccepted') ] );

                return Redirect::action('OauthController@getAuthorise')->withErrors($e);
            }

            // Generate an authorisation code
            $code = $this->authserver->getGrantType('authorization_code')
                    ->newAuthoriseRequest('user', $params['user_id'], $params);

            // Redirect the user back to the client with an authorisation code
            $redirectResponse = [ 'code' => $code, 'state' => isset( $params['state'] ) ? $params['state'] : '' ];
        }

        // If the user has denied the client so redirect them back without an authorisation code
        if(Input::get('deny') !== null) {
            $redirectResponse = [ 'error'         => 'access_denied',
                                  'error_message' => $this->authserver->getExceptionMessage('access_denied'),
                                  'state'         => isset( $params['state'] ) ? $params['state'] : '' ];
        }

        if(isset( $redirectResponse )) {
            return Redirect::to(RedirectUri::make($params['redirect_uri'], $redirectResponse));
        } else {
            //we didn't get a valid response from the user, let's start again
            return Redirect::action('OauthController@getIndex');
        }
    }

    public function postAccessToken() {
        try {

            // Tell the auth server to issue an access token
            $this->authserver->setAccessTokenTTL(15768000); //ask user for permissions every half year
            $response = $this->authserver->issueAccessToken();

            return Response::json($response, 200, [ 'cache-control' => 'Cache-Control', 'Pragma' => 'no-cache' ]);

        } /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | An error occurred inside the library
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        catch(Server\Exception\ClientException $e) {

            // Throw an exception because there was a problem with the client's request
            $exceptionType = Server\Authorization::getExceptionType($e->getCode());
            $response      = [
                'error'             => $exceptionType,
                'error_description' => $e->getMessage()
            ];

            // Grab the code out of the header string
            $code = substr(current(Server\Authorization::getExceptionHttpHeaders($exceptionType)), 9, 3);

            return Response::json($response, $code);

        } /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | An error occurred outside the library, probably a generic server error
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        catch(Exception $e) {

            // Throw an error when a non-library specific exception has been thrown
            $response = [ 'error' => 'undefined_error', 'error_description' => $e->getMessage() ];

            return Response::json($response, 500);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because OAuth is generally an authorization protocol:

> The user that authenticated with the Authorization Server has granted
>   permission for your Laravel webapp to call endpoints that are
>   protected by the authorization server. It would use the `access_token`
>   to do that.

What you want is to use this as a means of identifying the user as a valid user in **your system**. You can do this by calling the `userinfo` endpoint on the AS (with the `access_token`) and then creating a session for that user in your server. It seems that Laravel has a way of [manually logging in users](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually), so you would call that method after `userinfo` returns with success. (a proxy for an authenticated user).

`userinfo` is an endpoint that typically returns information about the user (e.g. e-mail, name, id, etc). You can use that information and associate it to the user record in your side.

Comment: Yes this is fine, and what we are doing, But what I am having an issue with is when the user comes back to our webapp after closing their browser the user is again presented with the login button, clicking that takes them back to the authorization server to enter their username/password to get authenticated. But they are also presented with the *authorization* requested again. I am wondering how best to avoid this.

Comment: What are you using as the AuthZ server? Looks like that is forcing the consent from the user each time.

Comment: I am using league/oauth2-server I will add the oauth controller into the question.

Comment: Try using Laravel/Socialite or artdarek/oauth-4-laravel